# Namespacing styles break Bootstrap carousel transition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-carousel

Namespacing styles breaks transitions.

I have a Bootstrap Carousel displaying the previous and next image. I have more than one Bootstrap Carousel, so I need different styles for each. Doing so breaks the transition.

If you comment the `.namespace` namespacing in the scss file and you will see it works fine. Why does this break? What is a possible fix?

**See** [**Not Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tehlivi/05syf03o/) 
**See [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tehlivi/vxvbLLbL/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid namespace">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://aszx.altervista.org/aatest/img/carousel/carousel-001.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://aszx.altervista.org/aatest/img/carousel/carousel-002.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://aszx.altervista.org/aatest/img/carousel/carousel-003.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .namespace {
    .carousel {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
        width: 150%;
        left: -25%;
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    }

    .carousel-control.left,
    .carousel-control.right {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
//original code from http://jsbin.com/jadahetoxi/3/edit?html,css,js,output

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    })
    $('.carousel .item').each(function() {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

**Bootstrap** v3.3.6 
**jQuery** v1.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your fiddle outputs look the same. Perhaps you already solved this? I'm viewing them in the most recent version of Mozilla Firefox, on a mac. Perhaps it's a browser specific issue?

It appears that your transitions are "fighting" with the default bootstrap stuff. It's not as much about having `.namespace` in there, it's about changing the position in CSS while JS is also altering the position.

I've done a few quick modifications to your fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/TinaBellVance/gavgngng/1/

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm running Chrome on Mac. However, I did just try Firefox and the slide transition doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: I'm running Firefox 46.0.1. I do see the issue in Chrome, however (using 50.0.2661.102).